# Twitter Update to API 1.1

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, twitter

My current code:

```
SLRequest *req = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                        requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                  URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"]
                                           parameters:[NSDictionary
                                                       dictionaryWithObjects:@[user]
                                                       forKeys:@[@"screen_name"]]];
    [req performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        if (urlResponse.statusCode == 200){
            id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];
            completionBlock(object);
        }else {
            if (error == nil)
                error = [API errorWithStatusCode:urlResponse.statusCode];
            errorBlock(error);
        }
    }];
```

I did made a Application on dev.twitter.com but I don't know how to implement the tokens I got from Twitter. How can I update to 1.1 without the user asking for their Twitter account?

Answer (score 0):

you need to `authenticate` your request to get the User Timeline, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207317/ios-how-to-fetch-tweet-from-twitter-api-1-1/17207745#17207745) 
this answer is using `FHSTwitterEngine` to `authenticate` the request and then create a search query, you can get the `user_timeline` instead of the search query.

Hope it helps you ^_^